# How to code a list in ASP.NET MVC when your base model isn't of type list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Update: As requested added extra code and error info.

I have seen many versions of this same error being asked and answered but not for the exact issue I have.

So I have an ASP.NET MVC app that has a `BaseViewModel` class, from which all other view models inherit, and is used in the `layout.cshtml` file.

I am adding a new view that needs to display a list of items pulled from a database. So the standard thing to code was to load a list of the new view model and send it to the new view and the view would add a new row to a table for every item in the list. This works fine without referencing to layout file. But when I add the reference like the below:

```
@model IEnumerable<EnrollmentMonitor.ViewModels.SystemListViewModel>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "System Index";
}
```

It throws this error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EnrollmentMonitor.ViewModels.SystemViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'EnrollmentMonitor.ViewModels.BaseViewModel'.

I understand fundamentally what is going on but I am not sure what the best way to fix this is. Is there a way without completely redesigning my model code?

I have tried making a SystemModel class that has the elements I need (this is what was in SystemListViewModel before:

```
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    
    namespace EnrollmentMonitor.ViewModels
    {
        public class SystemModel
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "System is required")]
            public string System { get; set; }
    
            [Display(Name = "Is Active?")]
            public string IsActive { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Then I made SystemListViewModel just have a single property that is a List of SystemModel:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace EnrollmentMonitor.ViewModels
{
    public class SystemListViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public List<SystemModel> Systems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My view now just takes the SystemListViewModel without the IEnumerable:

```
    @model EnrollmentMonitor.ViewModels.SystemListViewModel

    @{
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        ViewBag.Title = "System Index";
    }

<h2>Systems</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "NewSystem") | @Html.ActionLink("Configuration List", "ConfigurationIndex")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            System Name
        </th>   
        <th>
            Is Active?
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Systems)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.System)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsActive)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditSystem", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @if (item.IsActive == "Active")
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Disable", "DisableSystem", new { id = item.ID },
                    new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to disable this item?');" })
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Enable", "EnableSystem", new { id = item.ID },
                    new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to enable this item?');" })
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
    }

</table>
```

And lastly this is the layout file with some code redacted for security reasons:

```
@using EnrollmentMonitor.ViewModels
@model BaseViewModel


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@Model.Title</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/fontawesome/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/prettify")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/chart")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">*@
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="browerwarning" style="display:none"><center><b>Warning: You are using an outdated browser which is not supported.</b><br />Please use browsers supported by Aflac such as Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge.</center></div>
    <div class="body-content">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Enrollment Monitor", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                @if (Model.IsAuthorized("XX"))
                {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Transaction Summary", "TransSummary", "TransSummary")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Associate Search", "AgentSearch", "AgentSearch")</li>
                }
                <li class="dropdown dropdown-large">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        Reports & Tools
                        <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row">
                        @if (Model.IsAuthorized("XX"))
                        {
                            <li class="col-sm-4">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="dropdown-header">Transaction&nbsp;Reports</li>
                                    <li><a href="~/TransDetail/TransDetail">Transaction Details Report</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="~/PDFDetail/PDFGuidDetail">PDF Guid Report</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="~/PolicyDetail/PolicyDetail">Policy Detail Report</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="~/PolicyByEmployee/PolicyByEmployee">Policy by Employee Name</a></li>
                                    @if (Model.IsAuthorized("XX"))
                                    {
                                        <li><a href="~/TransactionError/TransactionError">Error Report</a></li>
                                    }
                                    @if (Model.IsAuthorized("XX"))
                                    {
                                        <li><a href="~/Error/Error">Error Report By Error Message</a></li>
                                    }
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-header">Associate&nbsp;Info&nbsp;Report</li>
                                    @*<li><a href="#">Transaction by Writing Number</a></li>*@
                                    <li><a href="~/AgentDetail/AgentDetail">Agent Details</a></li>
                                    @if (Model.IsAuthorized("XX"))
                                    {
                                        <li><a href="~/AgentLicense/AgentLicense">Agent License Information</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="~/AgentTraining/GetAgentTraining">Agent Training</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="~/AgentAppointment/AgentAppointment">Agent Appointment</a></li>
                                    }
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        }
                        @{var col = "12";
                            if (Model.AuthorizedAs("XX")) { col = "6"; }
                            if (Model.IsAuthorized("XX")) { col = "4"; }
                        }

                        <li class="col-sm-@col">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Productions&nbsp;Reports</li>
                                <li><a href="~/PolicyByChannelReport/PolicyByChannelReport">Policy Count by Channel</a></li>
                                <li><a href="~/PolicyWithChannel/PolicyWithChannel">New AP by Platform</a></li>
                                <li><a href="~/PolicyReportByState/PolicyReportByState">Policy by State</a></li>
                                <li><a href="~/PolicyCountReport/PolicyCountReport">Production Report</a></li>
                                <li><a href="~/PolicyVolumeReport/PolicyVolumeReport">Transaction Volume Report</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="~/MiscReports/MiscReports">Miscellaneous Reports</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown " style="background-color:ButtonFace">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">@Model.Env <b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#" onclick="return changeenv('prod');">Production</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" onclick="return changeenv('syst');">System Test</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" onclick="return changeenv('intg');">Integration</a></li>
                        <li><a herf="#" onclick="return changeenv('dev');">Development</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="body-content" id="body">
    @RenderBody()

    <hr />
    <footer>
        <div class="body-content">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="text-muted">Last Update: @Model.CurrentTime</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-right">

                <li class="text-muted">Login As: @Model.UserID Level: @Model.SecurityLevel</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    changeenv = function (env) {
        var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only
        var url = window.location.href;     // Returns full URL

        if (env == 'dev')
            window.location.href = '@Model.MonitorURL("dev")' + pathname;
        else if (env == 'intg')
            window.location.href = '@Model.MonitorURL("intg")' + pathname;
        else if (env == 'syst')
            window.location.href = '@Model.MonitorURL("syst")' + pathname;
        else if (env == 'prod')
            window.location.href = '@Model.MonitorURL("prod")' + pathname;

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Now I had some issues at first because I forgot to update the controller but  that did work. But I really didn't like it. So was there a better way?

Comment: Please provide the full error message.

Comment: And post the layout view too pls

Comment: The list of SystemListViewModel should be contained within a view model that inherits the base view model.  The layout expects a base view model, but instead is given a List of base view model.